# Complex CASE Expression Code

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an existing case statement I need to modify and it is giving me some trouble. The existing code:

```
CASE WHEN (DATEDIFF(Day, MAX(ContDataTranDate), ContDataEnd) + 1)
-(DATEDIFF(wk, MAX(ContDataTranDate), ContDataEnd) * 2)  
-(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, MAX(ContDataTranDate)) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
-(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, ContDataEnd) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) -1  = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END [Shipped1Day]
```

What I need to add:
I have 2 new columns, `SOFReleaseDateName` and `SOFReleaseDateValue`.
I need to change the existing statement to say that when `SOFReleaseDateName` is not null to use `SOFReleaseDateValue` instead of `ContDataTranDate` in the calculation currently using `ContDataTranDate` ELSE use the `ContDataTranDate`. I have tried many different ways.
`SOFReleaseDateValue` is also a Date.

Comment: You say you've *"tried many different ways"*, what were those ways?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a new case statement to front of the one you have that checks SOFReleaseDateName

```
CASE WHEN SOFReleaseDateName IS NOT NULL THEN
   CASE WHEN (DATEDIFF(Day, MAX(SOFReleaseDateValue ), ContDataEnd) + 1)
            -(DATEDIFF(wk, MAX(SOFReleaseDateValue ), ContDataEnd) * 2)  
            -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, MAX(SOFReleaseDateValue )) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
            -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, ContDataEnd) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) -1  = 1 
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0
    END
WHEN
    (DATEDIFF(Day, MAX(ContDataTranDate), ContDataEnd) + 1)
    -(DATEDIFF(wk, MAX(ContDataTranDate), ContDataEnd) * 2)  
    -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, MAX(ContDataTranDate)) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, ContDataEnd) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) -1  = 1 

    THEN 1 
    ELSE 0 
END [Shipped1Day]
```

you may need an ELSE instead of a WHEN after the `SOFReleaseDateName IS NOT NULL` case

```
CASE WHEN SOFReleaseDateName IS NOT NULL THEN
    CASE WHEN (DATEDIFF(Day, MAX(SOFReleaseDateValue ), ContDataEnd) + 1)
            -(DATEDIFF(wk, MAX(SOFReleaseDateValue ), ContDataEnd) * 2)  
            -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, MAX(SOFReleaseDateValue )) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
            -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, ContDataEnd) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) -1  = 1 
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0
    END
ELSE
     CASE WHEN (DATEDIFF(Day, MAX(ContDataTranDate), ContDataEnd) + 1)
            -(DATEDIFF(wk, MAX(ContDataTranDate), ContDataEnd) * 2)  
            -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, MAX(ContDataTranDate)) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
            -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, ContDataEnd) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) -1  = 1 
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
    END
END [Shipped1Day]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CASE WHEN (DATEDIFF(Day, MAX(case when SOFReleaseDateName is not null then SOFReleaseDateValue else ContDataTranDate end), ContDataEnd) + 1)
-(DATEDIFF(wk, MAX(case when SOFReleaseDateName is not null then SOFReleaseDateValue else ContDataTranDate end), ContDataEnd) * 2)  
-(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, MAX(case when SOFReleaseDateName is not null then SOFReleaseDateValue else ContDataTranDate end)) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
-(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, ContDataEnd) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) -1  = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END [Shipped1Day]
```

Comment: Replace all mentions of 'ContDataTranDate' with case statement above